# Converting NSData to NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I am parsing a URL, I am getting some data in a `NSMutableData` object i.e `urlData`. Now in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {}` I would like to convert the `urlData` to a `NSString`. I have tried with:

```
NSString *responseData =  [NSString stringWithCString:[urlData bytes] length:[urlData length]];   
NSString* responseData = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[urlData bytes]];   
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[urlData bytes] length:[urlData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;   
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];   
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I am either getting `null` in `NSString` object or PK(reverse Question Marks which i am unable to show you).

Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure your data you have in urlData is correct and really is a string?

Comment: @Nick Bull : i am parsing a .epub extension file and parsing that link and getting data in NSMutableData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

is the method you need to use. Your problem is either that you are not using the correct encoding or the data is not string data. NSLog the data and examine it to figure pout what it really is.

From the Apple documents:

> An NSString object initialized by converting the bytes in data into
>   Unicode characters using encoding. The returned object may be
>   different from the original receiver. Returns nil if the
>   initialization fails for some reason (for example if data does not
>   represent valid data for encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will work

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[urlData bytes] length:[urlData length] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy]; 
NSLog(@"urlData........%@",str);
```

Comment: `NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` is not an encoding option for `initWithBytes`, it is an `NSStringEncodingConversionOptions` option. Its value is 1 which is the same `NSASCIIStringEncoding` so this statement will just convert using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` which the OP already tried.

Comment: @Naayana : i am still getting the same thing, Thank u for your valuable answer. Now i have changed my logic and going in that way presently.